# Проблема со sprite renderer в Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity3d, спрайт

Я создал объект Hero и в него засунул sprite, но в этой строчке кода`sprite = GetComponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer>();` он обращается к sprite renderer внутри Hero, не к спрайту внутри объекта Hero. Как это исправить? (Я новичок в Unity)

Comment: А документация для слабаков?

Comment: [Прочитай, что написал](https://translate.google.com/?hl=ru&tab=TT&sl=en&tl=ru&text=Get%20Component%20In%20Children&op=translate).

Answer (score 2):

```
sprite = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite;
```

См. документацию: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SpriteRenderer.html

Comment: @Danii а зачем тогда вы что-то пытаетесь положить в sprite? lХотя на самом деле нужно из этого что-то вынуть? Где логика?.....................`sprite.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>()`